# Get key name in one member hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a data structure for a multi-level lookup table that looks something like this

```
$lookupTable = @{
    'a' = @{
        'a1' = 'A One'
        'a2' = 'A Two'
        'a3' = 'A Three'
    }
    'b' = @{
        'b1' = 'B One'
        'b2' = 'B Two'
        'b3' = 'B Three'
    }
}
```

I use a data structure like this to pass an arbitrary number of new and revised values to update the table, like this.

```
$hash=@{'a'=@{'a4'='A Four'}
        'b'=@{'b4'='B Four'}
        'c'=@{'c1'='C One'
              'c2'='C Two'
             }
       }
```

I can then use nested foreach loops to get the key names to add or update.

However, I also need to extract just a single value, and I want to keep a similar data structure so I can pass just one hash table to specify exactly what value I am looking for, such as `$getValue = @{'b'='b1'}`.

But to do that I need to get the key name at the first(only) index. I have tried

```
Write-Host "$($getValue.GetEnumerator[0])"
Write-Host "$($getValue.keys.GetEnumerator[0])"
Write-Host "$($getValue.GetEnumerator[1])"
Write-Host "$($getValue.keys.GetEnumerator[1])"
```

and none work. I could use a foreach again, which will only look once, but that seems inelegant. So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Just to verify the loop based approach works, I did this

```
foreach ($key in $getValue.keys) {
    if ($key) {
        Write-Host "$key $($getValue.$key) = $($lookupTable.$key.($getValue.$key))"
    }
    break
}
```

and it does indeed come back with b b1 = B one. but what an ugly way to do it.

Dang, getting closer!
`$key = $getValue.keys[0]` does provide a key of **b**. But `$value = $getValue.$key` doesn't return **b1** as expected. However, `$value = $getValue[$key]` does! however, then trying
$key = $getValue.keys[0]
$value = $getValue[$key]

```
Write-Host "$key $($getValue[$key]) = $($lookupTable.$key.$value)"
```

doesn't come back with the actual final value. Grr. More coffee and try again.

AHA! $getValue.keys[0] doesn't return a string. But if you cast to a string then everything is dandy. So

```
$key = [string]$getValue.keys[0]
$value = $getValue.$key
Write-Host "$key $value = $($lookupTable.$key.$value)"
```

works a treat. So I answered my own question. I guess I'll let the mods decide if this might be educational for others, or should just be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this by declaring the `$getValue` not as a Hashtable, but rather as a simple array:

```
# define the value to get as array of keys. 
# Element 0 => the key for $lookupTable, 
# Element 1 => the key for the first nested hash
$getValue = 'b','b1'

# now, simply get the value you are looking for like this:
Write-Host $lookupTable[$getvalue[0]][$getValue[1]]

# or like so:
Write-Host $lookupTable.$($getvalue[0]).$($getvalue[1])

# or by using helper variables:
$lookupKey, $nestedKey = $getValue
Write-Host $lookupTable.$lookupKey.$nestedKey
```

All of the above will return the value `B One`

Comment: indeed, I came to the same conclusion in the last few hours. But I did learn a bit about hash tables making it work the other way, so that's good too. Now to apply it too production code.